# input array is longer than the number of columns in my table

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
int flag = 0;
int num = 0;
int price, totprice, qty;
string product;

private void ProductsGV_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    product = ProductsGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    //qty =  Convert.ToInt32(OrderQtyTb.Text);
    price = Convert.ToInt32(ProductsGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    //totprice = qty * price;
    flag = 1;
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OrderQtyTb.Text == "")
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Quantity");
    else if (flag == 0)
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Product");
    else
    {
        num = num + 1;
        qty = Convert.ToInt32(OrderQtyTb.Text);
        totprice = qty * price;
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Rows.Add(num, product, qty, price, totprice);
        OrdersGV.DataSource = table;
        flag = 0;
    }
}
```

I get an error on this line:

```
table.Rows.Add(num, product, qty, price, totprice);
```

> input array is longer than the number of columns in this table

The purpose of the code is to let me input a quantity. Then I will click on the product list table and after that I will now click the "Add to Order" button. I want the button to reveal the new quantity on the `OrdersGV`.

Comment: You can show respect for those who might help you by making the basic effort to ensure your code samples are well-formatted, instead of indented way to the right.

Comment: `input array is longer than the number of columns in this table` - what exactly is unclear to you in this error message? How many columns does the table have?

Comment: Spoiler: None. Because you create a new one right above the line that throws.

Comment: You can create a new row by getting the Table from your Gridview and calling the [NewRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.newrow?view=net-7.0) method on it. Then fill that row.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
```

This makes a brand new table, with no columns defined at all, and the `DataTable` type requires you to use a well-defined schema.

*You don't want to create a new DataTable here.* You want to find the **existing** data source that is already showing in the grid, and add the row to that. If (and only if!) there is none, you need to create a DataTable object [with defined Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-columns-to-a-datatable).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `new the DataTable`. It should only be `initial with the dataSource of OrdersGV`:

```
 DataTable table = OrdersGV.DataSource as DataTable;
 table.Rows.Add(num, product, qty, price, totprice);
```

Comment: Hello sir. I try the code you have replied, but it is still not working. Then the error says, 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'